# One's complement adder

Tags: twos-complement, ones-complement

I am not sure this is the proper section of the forum, in case please just let me know.

I am studying Computer Organization and Design, and the legendary [Patterson & Hannessy](https://books.google.it/books?id=EVhgAAAAQBAJ&pg=PA79&lpg=PA79&dq=one+complement+adder+extra+step&source=bl&ots=OiwWBIb7KG&sig=jUE94lbLnzsj8GqxLU-0Xa5FqYM&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiM78C855nRAhWpAsAKHZXIB1AQ6AEILjAD#v=onepage&q&f=false) states that "One's complement adders did need an extra step to subtract a number and hence two's complements dominates today".

What is the extra operation that does an one's complement require?

Comment: You're talking about negating a number. The sentence you're quoting talks about adding/subtracting two numbers. Different operations.

Comment: Got it, I am going to make the question simpler.

Comment: Consider `5 + -2`. How would you do it in one's complement? How in two's complement?

Comment: If I am not wrong, 0101 + (1101 + 1) for the two's complement and 0101 + 1101 for the one's complement.

Comment: 0101 + (1101 + 1) = 0011, which is 3. Good. But 0101 + 1101 = 0010, which is 2, so your proposed one's complement adder gives the wrong result.

Comment: Here is the problem. To get the correct answer, I should add 1. But, by doing this, it would be identical to the two's complement.

Comment: No, the two's complement adder doesn't add 1. It just straight up adds two numbers, bit by bit. The clever bit is that negative numbers are represented in such a way that signed and unsigned addition use exactly the same algorithm, whereas with one's complement you need a runtime check in the signed adder. In other words, the two's complement adder gets 0101 and 1110 as inputs and it doesn't need to care whether 1110 represents -2 or 14.

Comment: Finally got it. Thank you for your patience. Why do not you make of the comment an answer, so that I can mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two's complement adder just straight up adds two numbers, bit by bit. The clever bit is that negative numbers are represented in such a way that signed and unsigned addition use exactly the same algorithm, whereas with one's complement you need a runtime check in the signed adder (negative inputs need an extra +1).

In other words, when you're doing `5 + -2` on a 4-bit adder, the two's complement adder gets 0101 and 1110 as inputs and it doesn't need to care whether 1110 represents -2 or 14.